# jQuery ajax callback receiving incorrect json result

Tags: json, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jsonresult

In my asp.net mvc 4 web app my action in the controller seems to return a invalid data to the jquery ajax callback... The action is doing a ping to an IP and it is called several times from several ajax calls in order to do pings to several IPs.

A piece of my action in the controller (below what is returned):

```
            Response.ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
            Response.StatusCode = (int)(packetsLost < 4 ? HttpStatusCode.OK : HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            return new JsonResult()
            {                    
                ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                Data = new
                {
                    sent = 4,
                    received = 4 - packetsLost,
                    lost = packetsLost,
                    percentLost = (int) (packetsLost / 4 * 100),
                    responseStatus01 = statuses[0],
                    responseStatus02 = statuses[1],
                    responseStatus03 = statuses[2],
                    responseStatus04 = statuses[3],
                    responseMessage01 = responseStatuses[0],
                    responseMessage02 = responseStatuses[1],
                    responseMessage03 = responseStatuses[2],
                    responseMessage04 = responseStatuses[3],
                    rtt01 = rtt[0],
                    rtt02 = rtt[1],
                    rtt03 = rtt[2],
                    rtt04 = rtt[3],
                    ttl01 = ttl[0],
                    ttl02 = ttl[1],
                    ttl03 = ttl[2],
                    ttl04 = ttl[3],
                    minRtt = roundTripTimes.Count == 0 ? "0" : string.Format("{0}ms", roundTripTimes.Min()),
                    maxRtt = roundTripTimes.Count == 0 ? "0" : string.Format("{0}ms", roundTripTimes.Max()),
                    avgRtt = roundTripTimes.Count == 0 ? "0" : string.Format("{0}ms", roundTripTimes.Average())
                },                   
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet 
            };
```

and jquery ajax call:

```
ajax({
        url: '/Controller/Action/',
        type: 'POST'
    }).then(function (data) {
        var _data;
        try {
            _data = $.parseJSON(data);
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert("Something went bad!!!");
        }
    }, function (data) {
        var _data;
        try {
            _var = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert("Something went bad!!!");
        }
    });
```

1) When action returns http status code OK (200) data.responseText in the jquery ajax callback is empty so I convert data instead (that contains correct data) but for some reason it is crashing when converting using parseJSON(data): error catched says invalid character... I do not know why...

2) When action return http status code NotFound (404) data.responseText sometimes (not always) is empty and statusText within data is "error" so neither I do not understand it....

Action in the controller always is returning the correct data....

Could someone help me to detect this error? or right me in the right direction....

**UPDATED:**
From ie dev tools, in network, I have observed that some pings are cancelled and then when trying to process them it returns empty responseText to the ajax callback so when trying to parse it, it crashes. I have observed that If I set the timeout for ping to a lower value, for example, 750ms, it is working but if i use the default timeout for ping, that is, 5sec, then it does not work: some pings are cancelled and when trying to serve them they are returning empty responseText that cause it to crash when trying to parse in ajax callback.